# SSIS: Why would I see 'The expression for variable "" failed evaluation.' but the package succeeds?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, etl

I have a .dtsx package that drops a flat file off in a folder. I'm using a variable (run as expression) so the package can dynamically suffix the file name with today's date.

The package runs successfully but throws a 
**"The expression for variable "FileLocation" failed evaluation."** 
error. No other error messages appear.

I've checked the case sensitivity between the variable and the expression wherever it appears and it seems fine.

Any idea why this happens and how I can fix it?

Thanks

LS23

Comment: I suspect the file is created with the initial value name because the expression failed. Provides us the variable initial value, the expression, and what is successfully for you, where is the file created ?

Comment: When you say the package runs successfully, do you mean it does everything it's supposed to do?   Or just that it reports completing successfully?

Comment: It does everything it's supposed to do yeah. The file is output to the correct File location using the variable and expression with the correct date suffix. It's all great! But it still throws the error message.

Comment: I managed to solve this in the end. There were a number of variables being processed as expressions that were creating a sort of circular reference within the data flow. Tidying it up stopped the error (and sped the whole thing up).